# WordPress 3.1: Using query_posts to do an AND search of categories

Tags: wordpress, categories, posts

I have posts that are categorised and can currently use the query_posts() function to do an *OR* search of posts based on their category, for example I can get all posts that are in category 1 OR 2 by calling query_posts('cat=1,2&orderby=date&showposts=5');

However I would like to do an *AND* search, so just getting posts that are in category 1 AND 2 instead.

Could anyone tell me how to do it please? WordPress documenentation mentions passing a **category__and** array of category ids, however this doesn't seem to work in 3.1. Do I need to use a custom SELECT query maybe or does WordPress have a neat way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the documentation [query_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)

```
query_posts( array( 'category__and' => array(1,3), 'posts_per_page' => 2, 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'DESC' ) );
```

(this combination will return posts belong to both Category 1 AND 3, showing just two (2) posts, in descending order by the title)

Comment: Thanks - I've tried it again and yea it does seem to work! I had tried it before as I put in the question, however I was testing it with a non-existent category e.g. (1,1000) to see whether it returned 0 posts and it didn't - it continued to return some. So I thought it was no longer supported as a post can't be in category 1000. But I've tried it again with some real category ids, and it does seem to be correctly restricting them - excellent

Comment: you could debug a bit and see what query's are actualy runned, maybe it tests to see if there are any posts in 1 and 1000 and if it doesn't find any it returns from 1 OR maybe it's a bug and you should report it but we can't tell for shure unless somebody makes some tests .

Answer (score 0):

```
query_posts( array( 'category__and' => array(1,3), 'posts_per_page' => 2, 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'DESC' ) );
```